# How can I expand all items in the treeview or collapse all branches when clicking on the (Expand All / Collapse All) button?

Tags: jquery

I have this TreeView, and I want to set up 2 buttons:

- the first one, when clicked, will expand all the items and branches in the tree, and
- the second one will collapse all the open items and branches in the TreeView.

The problem is I don't know the correct function in jQuery that will do that. I would appreciate your help with this.

```js
$.fn.extend({
  treed: function(o) {
    var openedClass = 'fa-minus-circle';
    var closedClass = 'fa-plus-circle';
    if (typeof o != 'undefined') {
      if (typeof o.openedClass != 'undefined') {
        openedClass = o.openedClass;
      }
      if (typeof o.closedClass != 'undefined') {
        closedClass = o.closedClass;
      }
    };
    //initialize each of the top levels
    var tree = $(this);
    tree.addClass("tree");
    tree.find('li').has("ul").each(function() {
      var branch = $(this); //li with children ul
      branch.prepend("<i class='indicator fas " + closedClass + "'></i>");
      branch.addClass('branch');
      branch.on('click', function(e) {
        if (this == e.target) {
          var icon = $(this).children('i:first');
          icon.toggleClass(openedClass + " " + closedClass);
          $(this).append("<div class='loading'><span class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'</span></div>");
          setTimeout(() => {
            $(this).find('.loading').remove();
            $(this).children().children().slideToggle(400);
          }, 400)
        }
      })
      branch.children().children().toggle();
    });
    //fire event from the dynamically added icon
    tree.find('.branch .indicator').each(function() {
      $(this).on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('li').click();
      });
    });
    //fire event to open branch if the li contains an anchor instead of text
    tree.find('.branch>a').each(function() {
      $(this).on('click', function(e) {
        $(this).closest('li').click();
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    });
    //fire event to open branch if the li contains a button instead of text
    tree.find('.branch>button').each(function() {
      $(this).on('click', function(e) {
        $(this).closest('li').click();
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    });
  }
});
//Initialization of treeviews
$('#tree1').treed();
$.fn.extend({
  treed: function(o) {
    var openedClass = 'fa-minus-circle';
    var closedClass = 'fa-plus-circle';
    if (typeof o != 'undefined') {
      if (typeof o.openedClass != 'undefined') {
        openedClass = o.openedClass;
      }
      if (typeof o.closedClass != 'undefined') {
        closedClass = o.closedClass;
      }
    };
    //initialize each of the top levels
    var tree = $(this);
    tree.addClass("tree");
    tree.find('li').has("ul").each(function() {
      var branch = $(this); //li with children ul
      branch.prepend("<i class='indicator fas " + closedClass + "'></i>");
      branch.addClass('branch');
      // declare a flag to toggle
      let flag = false;
      branch.on('click', function(e) {
        if (this == e.target) {
          // toggle on click
          flag = !flag;
          var icon = $(this).children('i:first');
          icon.toggleClass(openedClass + " " + closedClass);
          // show loader only when its opened, and collpase once toggled   
          if (flag) {
            $(this).append("<div class='loading'><span class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'</span></div>");
            setTimeout(() => {
              $(this).find('.loading').remove();
              $(this).children().children().slideToggle(400);
            }, 400)
          } else {
            $(this).children().children().slideToggle(400);
          }
        }
      })
      branch.children().children().toggle();
    });
    //fire event from the dynamically added icon
    tree.find('.branch .indicator').each(function() {
      $(this).on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('li').click();
      });
    });
    //fire event to open branch if the li contains an anchor instead of text
    tree.find('.branch>a').each(function() {
      $(this).on('click', function(e) {
        $(this).closest('li').click();
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    });
    //fire event to open branch if the li contains a button instead of text
    tree.find('.branch>button').each(function() {
      $(this).on('click', function(e) {
        $(this).closest('li').click();
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    });
  }
});

//Initialization of treeviews

$('#tree1').treed();

$('#tree2').treed({
  openedClass: 'fa-folder-open',
  closedClass: 'fa-folder'
});
```

```css
.tree {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.branch {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.tree,
.tree ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.tree ul {
  margin-left: 1em;
  position: relative
}

.tree ul ul {
  margin-left: .5em
}

.tree ul:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid
}

.tree li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 1em;
  line-height: 2em;
  color: #369;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
}

.tree ul li:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  margin-top: -1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 0
}

.tree ul li:last-child:before {
  background: #fff;
  height: auto;
  top: 1em;
  bottom: 0
}

.indicator {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.tree li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #369;
}

.tree li button,
.tree li button:active,
.tree li button:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #369;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  outline: 0;
}

.loading {
  font-style: italic;
}

.timeline {
  border-left: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

.timeline .timeline-item {
  position: relative;
}

.timeline .timeline-item:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
}

.timeline .timeline-item:after {
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
  left: -38px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 11px;
  width: 11px;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<section class="content">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <ul id="tree2">
              <button type="button" id="openall" class="btn btn-warning">open All</button>
              <button type="button " id="closeall " class="btn btn-info ">close All</button>
              <li>
                <a href="# ">TECH</a>
                <ul>
                  <li>Company Maintenance</li>
                  <li>
                    Employees
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        Reports
                        <ul>
                          <li>Report1
                            <ul>
                              <li>Report1
                                <ul>
                                  <li>Report1
                                    <ul>
                                      <li>Report1</li>
                                      <li>Report2</li>
                                      <li>Report3</li>
                                    </ul>
                                  </li>
                                  <li>Report2</li>
                                  <li>Report3</li>
                                </ul>
                              </li>
                              <li>Report2</li>
                              <li>Report3</li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li>Report2</li>
                          <li>Report3</li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li>Employee Maint.</li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li>Human Resources</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer text-body-secondary ">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</section>

<link rel="stylesheet " href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css ">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css " rel="stylesheet ">
<link rel="stylesheet " href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css " integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ " crossorigin="anonymous ">
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js " integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm " crossorigin="anonymous "></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js "></script>
```

Comment: Your best bet would be to refactor the `branch.on('click', function(e) {` code to its own function, possible as a jquery extension and then call that directly.  Otherwise you'll just be recreating the same code with slideUp/Down and icon swap.    You can't do a simple `$(".tree .branch").click()` as it *toggles* so if the user has already opened some, those will be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no jQuery function to do this by default, because you create in the code the tree functionnality by extending jQuery functions with your own. Here is a simple example, that just clicks on the branches depending if they are opened or closed.

What you could do is this: add functions to your tree variable in the construction in the `extend`. It's easier to return the tree at the end of the construction function so that you can get the result and call the functions directy on it, like I did in the buttons handlers.

I have removed a duplicated part of the code and fixed the indentation (be careful about indentation, or else it's har to see where a function starts and ends)

```js
$.fn.extend({

  treed: function (o) {

    var openedClass = 'fa-minus-circle';
    var closedClass = 'fa-plus-circle';

    if (typeof o != 'undefined'){
      if (typeof o.openedClass != 'undefined'){
        openedClass = o.openedClass;
      }
      if (typeof o.closedClass != 'undefined'){
        closedClass = o.closedClass;
      }
    }

    //initialize each of the top levels

    var tree = $(this);

    tree.addClass("tree");

    tree.find('li').has("ul").each(function () {

        var branch = $(this); //li with children ul
        branch.prepend("<i class='indicator fas " + closedClass + "'></i>");
        branch.addClass('branch');

        // declare a flag to toggle

        let flag = false;

        branch.on('click', function (e) {

            if (this == e.target) {
                // toggle on click

                flag = !flag;
                var icon = $(this).children('i:first');
                icon.toggleClass(openedClass + " " + closedClass); 

                // show loader only when its opened, and collpase once toggled
  
                if(flag) {
                  $(this).append("<div class='loading'><span class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'</span></div>"); 
                  setTimeout(()=>{
                    $(this).find('.loading').remove();
                    $(this).children().children().slideToggle(400);
                  }, 400)
                } else {
                  $(this).children().children().slideToggle(400);
                }
            }

        });

        branch.children().children().toggle();

    });

    //fire event from the dynamically added icon

    tree.find('.branch .indicator').each(function(){

      $(this).on('click', function () {
          $(this).closest('li').click();
      });

    });

    //fire event to open branch if the li contains an anchor instead of text

    tree.find('.branch>a').each(function () {

        $(this).on('click', function (e) {
            $(this).closest('li').click();
            e.preventDefault();
        });

    });

    //fire event to open branch if the li contains a button instead of text

    tree.find('.branch>button').each(function () {

        $(this).on('click', function (e) {
            $(this).closest('li').click();
            e.preventDefault();
        });

    });

    //adding "openAll" and "closeAll" functions to the tree

    tree.openAll = function(){
      tree.find('li').has("ul").each(function () {

        //finding if opened or closed from icon
        //TODO: find a simpler way, like a property set on "branch"?
        var branch = $(this); //li with children ul
        var icon = branch.children('i:first');

        //opening all closed ones
        if(icon.hasClass(closedClass)){
          branch.click();
        }
      });
    };
    tree.closeAll = function(){
      tree.find('li').has("ul").each(function () {

        //finding if opened or closed from icon
        //TODO: find a simpler way, like a property set on "branch"?
        var branch = $(this); //li with children ul
        var icon = branch.children('i:first');

        //opening all closed ones
        if(icon.hasClass(openedClass)){
          branch.click();
        }
      });      
    };

    //return the tree so we can store it in a var and call the functions

    return tree;

  }

});

    

//Initialization of treeviews

//$('#tree1').treed();

var tree2 = $('#tree2').treed({openedClass:'fa-folder-open', closedClass:'fa-folder'});

//code for the buttons
$('#openall').on('click', function(){
  tree2.openAll();
});
$('#closeall').on('click', function(){
  tree2.closeAll();
});
```

```css
.tree {

  overflow-y: auto;

}

.branch {

  white-space: nowrap;

}

.tree, .tree ul {

      margin:0;

      padding:0;

      list-style:none;

      margin-left:10px;

    }

    .tree ul {

      margin-left:1em;

      position:relative

    }

    .tree ul ul {

      margin-left:.5em

    }

    .tree ul:before {

      content:"";

      display:block;

      width:0;

      position:absolute;

      top:0;

      bottom:0;

      left:0;

      border-left:1px solid

    }

    .tree li {

      margin:0;

      padding:0 1em;

      line-height:2em;

      color:#369;

      font-weight:700;

      position:relative;

    }

    .tree ul li:before {

      content:"";

      display:block;

      width:10px;

      height:0;

      border-top:1px solid;

      margin-top:-1px;

      position:absolute;

      top:1em;

      left:0

    }

    .tree ul li:last-child:before {

      background:#fff;

      height:auto;

      top:1em;

      bottom:0

    }

    .indicator {

      margin-right:5px;

    }

    .tree li a {

      text-decoration: none;

      color:#369;

    }

    .tree li button, .tree li button:active, .tree li button:focus {

      text-decoration: none;

      color:#369;

      border:none;

      background:transparent;

      margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;

      padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;

      outline: 0;

    }

    .loading {

      font-style: italic;

    }

.timeline {

  border-left: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 90%);

  position: relative;

  list-style: none;

}

.timeline .timeline-item {

  position: relative;

}

.timeline .timeline-item:after {

  position: absolute;

  display: block;

  top: 0;

}

.timeline .timeline-item:after {

  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);

  left: -38px;

  border-radius: 50%;

  height: 11px;

  width: 11px;

  content: "";

}
```

```html
<section class="content">

  <div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="card">

    <div class="card-body">              

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4">

        <ul id="tree2">

<button type="button" id ="openall"class="btn btn-warning" id ">open All</button>
<button type="button" id="closeall" class="btn btn-info">closeAll</button>
          <li>

          <a href="#">TECH</a>

          <ul>

            <li>Company Maintenance</li>

            <li>

              Employees

              <ul>

                <li>

                Reports

                <ul>

                  <li>Report1

                  <ul>

                  <li>Report1

                  <ul>

                  <li>Report1

                  <ul>

                  <li>Report1</li>

                  <li>Report2</li>

                  <li>Report3</li>

                </ul>

                  </li>

                  <li>Report2</li>

                  <li>Report3</li>

                </ul>

                  </li>

                  <li>Report2</li>

                  <li>Report3</li>

                </ul>

                  </li>

                  <li>Report2</li>

                  <li>Report3</li>

                </ul>

                </li>

                <li>Employee Maint.</li>

              </ul>

            </li>

            <li>Human Resources</li>

          </ul>

          </li>

             </ul>

      </div>        

      </div>

   </div>

  <div class="card-footer text-body-secondary">

</div> 

</div>  <!-- /.container-fluid -->

   </section>

                    

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css">

   <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: I only want it to open and close treeview items when I press the open and close buttons and not after two seconds

Comment: @Satyntod yes it was just an example, then I edited the answer to implement the buttons instead, and I forgot to remove the timeout example. I edited it out

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, brother